# Prevent Keybord push up webview at iOS app using phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Whenever i am click on textfield or datapicker in iOS app, The Navigationbar moves up with scroll. It may be webview is going up when keybord up.
When Keybord is not up screen looks like in below screenshot:

[image]

When i am touch on textfield "Type the Number here" keybord moves up and looks like in below screenshot:

[image]

Same as in other page which has data picker, Navigation bar is not work like fixed as in below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input').on('focus', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
setTimeout(
    function(){
        windows.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using setTimeout at any web app. Try ".scrollTop(0)" if you are using jquery on blur event.

I had a similar problem once, it's not the best solution, but I remember I change my app configuration so it's not fullscreen (I set it so it shows the top bar) and that fixed my problem. It was an issue on some phonegap/cordova versions.

Comment: I have also change my app setting, tried with not fullscreen but it not solved my problem. can you give me demo link of your code ?